# WP List Pages - Add Title Attributes to Anchors

Tags: html, title, walker, wp-list-pages, code

Using the default `wp_list_pages()` is there an easy way / filter to add title attribute to the anchors? Right now it just spits out the anchor with no title attribute but I would like  to add it on just as the page title or something:

`<a href="http://www.url.com" title="Test Page">Test Page</a>`

Now I know I can do this using a big nasty walker but I feel like that's many lines of code for such a small thing. Is there a simple way / easy way to add the Title Attribute to `wp_list_pages()` anchors? Think code-golf.

Comment: What would you put into that attribute? In your example, you are repeating the link text – this is terrible for screen reader users and the main reason why so many title attributes were removed in WordPress.

Answer (score 1):

No. Unfortunately you're looking at a walker, or a custom replacement function, as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12353076/wp-list-pages-isnt-showing-title-attribute